# MFFS = instant kill?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Does an MFFS forcefield coming from a projector linked to a defense station kill an intruder instantly, even if the forcefield is only switched on for a very short period?

Comment: I have been told it does, but I've never tried MFFS for myself to know for sure

Comment: I think so. I have not used it in a while, but I'm pretty sure it effectively uses /kill, but I know the behavior has changed since I last used it (it used to kill opped players in creative mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the forcefield simply wont allow people inside (if they teleport in somehow then they are in)

Adding a defence station will give you the option to warn players, search their inventories (and remove banned items) and insta-kill any intruders.

So to answer the main question: **Yes, it's insta-kill**

source [here](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/MFFS_Defence_Station)

Also, personally I used them a lot for secure storage rooms

Comment: Your source just says it kills, like the MFFS interface says, but it says nothing about the time it takes to do so...